# Progress bar on hibernate/c3p0 reconnect

Tags: java, swing, hibernate, c3p0

I am using a hibernate with c3p0 in a swing application, to access database. c3p0 is configurated with `c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckout=true`. So if database drops connection (for exapmple after timeout) c3p0 establishes a new connection for me.

It works fine, but if DB is not accessable, c3p0 freezes GUI for some amount of time, prints on colsole the fallowing message

```
26.06.2013 11:42:46,568 WARN [ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner run] com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$DeadlockDetector@27d8f985 -- APPARENT DEADLOCK!!! Creating emergency threads for unassigned pending tasks!
26.06.2013 11:42:46,573 WARN [ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner run] com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$DeadlockDetector@27d8f985 -- APPARENT DEADLOCK!!! Complete Status:
        Managed Threads: 3
        Active Threads: 3
        Active Tasks:
                com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@1636d880 (com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#2)
                com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@6abfc6e4 (com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#1)
                com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@549ad97c (com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#0)
        Pending Tasks:
                com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$1DestroyResourceTask@23c8749
                com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@53d5cac4
Pool thread stack traces:
        Thread[com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#2,6,main]
                java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
                com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1805)
                com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:547)
        Thread[com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#1,6,main]
                java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
                com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1805)
                com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:547)
        Thread[com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#0,6,main]
                java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
                com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1805)
                com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:547)
```

and then after ~7 seconds an ecxeption `org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection` will be thrown. All this time GUI is blocked. What i actually want to do, is to show some progress bar (indeterminate) with some resonable message, like "Connection lost, trying to reconnect". How can i achive that? Maybe c3p0 has some callbacks for stuff like this?

Comment: I doubt a connection pool will have **any** affordances for GUIs. You should perform all database tasks asynchronously.

Comment: Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread) - the GUI will 'freeze' when that happens. Instead of calling `Thread.sleep(n)` implement a Swing `Timer` for repeating tasks or a `SwingWorker` for long running tasks.  See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.

Comment: @AndrewThompson normally db access is not really a long running task. But if db is not accessable and c3p0 trying to reconnect it will be a one. I don't want to show a progress bar every time i access db, only if it takes too long. Actually i could start a timer every time for that. But the simmplest way would be just find some callbacks in c3p0.